# How can I better optimize this Hive query for speed?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

What I am looking to do is better optimize these Hive queries in PySpark with Spark Context, as seen below, for better speed. Right now, when doing the Hive table comparison for big tables, it ends up taking a ridiculous amount of time (221 minutes wall-clock real time for some). My question is, looking at my script below for reconciliation, is there any suggestions on ways to improve the performance and speed of my queries? Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Particularly of note to see is this:

```
  # Initializing Passed Parameters

    FIRST_TBL = sys.argv[1]

    SECOND_TBL = sys.argv[2]


    # Defining Spark Context and Hive Context

    GLBL_CONF = SparkConf().setAppName("No TouchPoint Refine Load Wrapper")

    SC = SparkContext(conf=GLBL_CONF)

    HC = HiveContext(SC)

    CLMS_DF = HC.sql("describe {0}".format(FIRST_TBL))

    CLMS = CLMS_DF.select("col_name").collect()

    TYPES = CLMS_DF.select("data_type").collect()

    CLMS_LIST=[]

    TYPES_LIST=[]

    CLMS_STR=""

    for c in CLMS:

        CLMS_LIST.append(c.col_name)

    for t in TYPES:

        TYPES_LIST.append(t.data_type)

    for i,clms in enumerate(CLMS_LIST):

        clms_lower = clms.lower()

        if(not("add_user_nm" in clms_lower or "add_usr_nm" in clms_lower or "add_user" in clms_lower or "add_usr" in clms_lower or "add_tms" in clms_lower or "updt_user" in clms_lower or "updt_usr" in clms_lower or "updt_user_nm" in clms_lower or "updt_usr_nm" in clms_lower or "updt_tms" in clms_lower or clms_lower in EXCLUDED_CLMS_LIST)):

            if("partition information" in clms_lower):

                break

            else:

                if(TYPES_LIST[i].lower() == 'date' or TYPES_LIST[i].lower() == 'timestamp'):

                    max1 = HC.sql("select to_date(max({0})) as max_dt from {1} where to_date({0})<>'2099-12-31'".format(clms_lower,FIRST_TBL)).first()

                    max2 = HC.sql("select to_date(max({0})) as max_dt from {1} where to_date({0})<>'2099-12-31'".format(clms_lower,SECOND_TBL)).first()

                    CLMS_STR = CLMS_STR + "case when to_date({0}) = '{1}' or to_date({0}) = '{2}' or to_date({0}) = '2019-05-20' or to_date({0}) = '2019-05-21' or to_date({0}) = '2019-05-22' then cast('2020-06-06' as {3}) else to_date({0}) end as {0},".format(clms_lower,max1['max_dt'],max2['max_dt'],TYPES_LIST[i])

                else:

                    CLMS_STR = CLMS_STR+clms+","

        else:

            LOGGER.info("{0}".format(clms_lower))

    CLMS_STR = CLMS_STR[:-1]

    df1 = HC.sql("select {0} from {1} {2}".format(CLMS_STR,FIRST_TBL,WHERE_CLAUSE))

    df2 = HC.sql("select {0} from {1} {2}".format(CLMS_STR,SECOND_TBL,WHERE_CLAUSE))

 
    df1_minus_df2 = df1.subtract(df2)

    df1_minus_df2_count = df1_minus_df2.count()

 
    df2_minus_df1 = df2.subtract(df1)

    df2_minus_df1_count = df2_minus_df1.count()

 
    df1_count = df1.count()

    df2_count = df2.count()


    df1_minus_df2_log = LOG_PATH + 'First_minus_second_' + str(DATE) + '_' + str(TIME)

    df2_minus_df1_log = LOG_PATH + 'Second_minus_first_' + str(DATE) + '_' + str(TIME)
    df1_minus_df2.limit(10000).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save(df1_minus_df2_log)
    df2_minus_df1.limit(10000).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save(df2_minus_df1_log)
```

What I am aiming to do is take in two large tables, and basically calculate counts and then find their comparative differences.

Comment: This is really hard to read, and it's not clear what your queries are supposed to do. Can you describe your problem in detail, and at best show snippets for the queries?

Comment: Abbreviated the code more - I am just looking to calculate table counts and compare their differences, and then write their differences to another csv file.